# How to perfectly calculate height required for UILabel where attributed string contains HTML tags

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout

I am parsing JSON response from Google Direction API, It is having html_instructions. I want to display it on UILabel. But not getting any perfect solution for calculating height required for UILabel.

html_instructions are as follows:

`Merge onto <b>Shankar Sheth Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by the gas station (on the left)</div>`

I have tried solutions mentioned on stackoverflow like using `sizeThatFits()` and `boundingRectWithSize()`, It is giving me correct height for html_instructions not having `<div>` tag, but it leaves extra space when html_instructions are having `<div>` tags.

Please any tell me how to get exact required height for UILabel with attributed text containing html tags like `<div>`

Comment: you can use UIwebview to show this data

Answer (score 1):

I always use this `UILabel` extension and it works with HTML tag too. There's no reason it shouldn't work

```
extension UILabel {

    func sizeForString(string: NSString, constrainedToWidth width: Double) -> CGSize {

        return string.boundingRectWithSize(
            CGSize(
                width: width,
                height: DBL_MAX
            ),
            options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName : self.font
            ],
            context: nil).size
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you LucaD and @Tyson Vignesh for your solutions ..2nd one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIWebView to load the html string using following method,

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(nullable NSURL *)baseURL;
```

like

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

after the htmlString loaded

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

the above delegate method will be called. Here you can get the content size of the webView. with that you can set the height of the UIWebView perfectly

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

```
let rowhtmlString = "Merge onto <b>Shankar Sheth Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by the gas station (on the left)</div>"

let htmlData = NSString(string: rowhtmlString ).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)

let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes:nil)
```

then assign the attributedString to your label